# Optimal control

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Consider the optimal control problem with an optimal trajectory $x^*(t)$ and an initial point $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{x}=A x + Bu 
\\\
J=\int^\infty_0(x_2^2+\epsilon u^2)dt
\end{split}
\end{equation}
whera $(A,B)$ is minimal. How do I analyze $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}x^*(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an analysis of your problem in the following articles

[Jacobson et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1099360)
[Flaherty et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1101574)

your problem deals with bang-bang or singular controls. It is also possible that the optimal control chatters.